# How do print out the name of thread currently running on a specific non-thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading, this

I've found answers on how to print out the name of a specific thread when you are in the class `Thread` or a class subclassing `Thread`.

i.e. `this.getName();`

However, this isn't working for me when I'm in my class `QueueManager<T>`. For example in my method, `removeFromQueue()`, I want to print out which thread is pulling from the queue. But when I use `this`, it refers to the class `QueueManager<T>` and not the current Thread.

How do I refer to the current thread from inside this class?

```
public T removeFromQueue(){
        synchronized (this) {
            T item = null;

            if (!isEmpty()){
                item = queue.removeLast();
                if (WebServer.DEBUG) System.out.println(item + " removed from " + item.getClass() + "Queue" + "\nby " + this.);
                //If queue was full until right now, notify waiting socket threads that they can add something 
                if (getSize() == (maxQueueSize - 1)){
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
            return item; //If queue is empty, null is returned.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The name of the current thread is always given by

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```